# jQuery dropdown menu closes on click and hold

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this conundrum: 
I have an animated menu with a transition effect on the `<a class="header__user__company>` tag click. When I unfocus the element, the drop down menu disappears again. However, when I click on any link within the `<ul>`, I get to my page but the menu closes in the meantime. As well as my no1 bug: when I click on the `<a>` within the `<li>`, and hold my mouse button, the menu goes away and im left holding a click in the "air". I know I cant focus things that aren't the `input`, `a` or `select` tags (like I tried  :) ) Any thoughts?

Animated Dropdown menu which looks like this in html:

```
<div class="header__user">
    <a href="" class="header__user__company">Name of Company</a>
    <div class="user__nav">
       <ul>
          <li>
             <a href="/something1">Something1</a>
          </li>
          <li>
             <a href="/something2">Something2</a>
          </li>
          <li>
             <a href="/something3">Something3</a>
          </li>
       </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

This css:

```
.header__user .user__nav {
    position: absolute;
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height .4s;
}

.profile-transition {
    max-height: 170px;
}
```

and the jQuery:

```
// on click expand/collapse profile menu in header

$(".header__user__company").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".user__nav").toggleClass("profile-transition");
});

//close profile menu when clicking outside of the box

$(".header__user").focusout(function() {
    if($(".user__nav").hasClass("profile-transition")) {
        $(".user__nav").removeClass("profile-transition");
    }
});
```

Any thoughts? Please

Comment: It's your .focusout function, if you aren't going to use standard CSS for it then you need to check the position of the mouse before removing the class that shows the menu. If I were you I'd look at using the defacto standard of just showing your menu on hover and not making the user click to see the menu.

Comment: You say that when you click your link you get to your page but the menu closes. If you are loading a new page, this menu is going to revert to it's default state as the whole page is redrawn. If you are catching the link though, and you want the menu to stay open on click, then you should probably have it close on mouseout instead (that's the expect behavior.)

Comment: @AdamH I agree with you whole heartedly. On hover is def the best way but this time the client wants the menu to appear and reappear on a click function :') @Will yeah, I tried mouseout and it works, but the client wants the menu on click. My biggest problem is if the user clicks on the menu but doesn't "unclick" it still triggers the focusout, and the menu disappears as the user still holds the click. I tried to `trigger("focus");` on the menu, so that that it gets its focus but to no avail. I'll try playing around with the `<a>` tags within ul and focus then on hover.maybe it will work

Comment: @ChronicLogic if you need to implement the click method then you have 2 options; 1) Close the menu when another part of the page is clicked that isn't your open button or an item in the menu. 2) Update your focusout function to check the coordinates of the mouse and make sure it's not over the menu before closing.

Comment: @AdamH hmmm ill give it a shot!